# How to add custom visual element for custom HTML element in TinyMCE 6

Tags: tinymce, custom-element, tinymce-6

I have this HTML code:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>

<my-custom-tag></my-custom-tag>

<p>...dolor sit amet...</p>
```

In this case default behavior of TinyMCE is skip from rendering the custom tag, because don't know what should do with it.

How can I tell to TinyMCE "if you see the `my-custom-tag` in the HTML code, then replace it to an image only in rendered version of code, and don't touch the code"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow your custom tag in the [content filtering options](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#custom_elements), like so:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  custom_elements: 'my-custom-tag'
});
```